# How to get data like xpath and ids from a minimized webpage using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

the issue am dealing with is trying to get selenium to run in the background while getting data like webpage elements xpath and ids and being able to use it while remaining activity in the background and not keep poping up browser tab in front of other running programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try running your browser in headless mode. Here is a code snippet of the function that gives the instance of chrome in headless mode.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def browser_open(headless=False):
    options = Options()  
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("no-default-browser-check")
    options.add_argument("no-first-run")
    options.add_argument("no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("window-size=1300x744")
    if headless == True:
        options.add_argument("headless")

    chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "chromedriver"), chrome_options=options)
    chrome_browser.maximize_window()
    return chrome_browser
```

Comment: didnt know selenium have this feature, this definitely make it simpler, thanks